# Sklearn training data and test data is not same size

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to do a linear model in sklearn, and therefore i want to test the model, that i have implemented using some error functions.

First i chose the features for my `X` and `y` axis.

```py
#Predict the average parking rates per month
X = df[['Number of weekly riders', 'Price per week',
       'Population of city', 'Monthly income of riders']]

y = df['Average parking rates per month']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

 #only 20% test size because we are working with a small dataset 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=101)

lm = LinearRegression()

lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

after i fitted the model i try to use some of the error functions from the `metrics` package from sklearn

but apparently i can't use any of the functions, because there is not an equal amount of test and train data

```py
print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_train))  
print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_train))  
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_train)))
```

`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6, 21]`

is it really true, that you need the same size of train and test data, in order to run the error functions?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with those `metrics`? If you want to test the model's performance, you need to do `mse(lm.predict(X_test), y_test)`, not among the train and test labels.

Comment: @Chris I suspect the point is to compare metrics on train and test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use train/test-split you want to devide the training and test data:

[image]

The idea is that you train your algorithm with your training data and then test it with unseen data. So all the metrics do not make any sense with `y_train` and `y_test`. What you try to compare is then the prediction and the `y_test` this works then like:

```
y_pred_test = lm.predict(X_test)
metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred_test)
```

It is also possible to get an idea on the training scores; you can do that by predicting on the training data:

```
y_pred_train = lm.predict(X_train)
metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_train, y_pred_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare `y_test` and `y_predict` which is the output of `x_test` through your regressor.

Answer (score 0):

The following will raise an `inconsistent numbers of samples` error.

```
metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_train)
```

The reason is because the training set and the testing set has different number of rows.

In the rare case of them having the same number of rows, the above statement still doesn't make sense: there's no use of comparing the test set labels to training set labels.

Instead, you should obtain the predictions to your testing features(`X_test`) by inputting `X_test` to `lm`:

```
y_hat = lm.predict(X_test)  # y_hat: predictions
```

Then, these metrics would make sense:

```
metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_hat)
```